How to calculate how many bytes to extend a program when upgrading a deployed program?
Upgrading an existing program throws an error if the new program exceeds the size of the deployed program:
Error: Deploying program failed: RPC response error -32002: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: account data too small for instruction

You can extend the size of a program by running:
solana program extend <PROGRAM_ID> <ADDITIONAL_BYTES>

But how do you calcuate exactly how many additional bytes are required?

I'm not sure if this would work but you can maybe check what the current size is of the program is and then deploy the new program on devnet and calculate the difference.

Does this answer your question? https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/14434/how-can-i-find-out-how-much-sol-i-will-need-to-deploy-an-anchor-program
